# how to pass custom payload data in getInitialMessage and extract it in Flutter Firebase

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am making Flutter push notifications app with Awesome notifications.

```
{
    "to":"NTQyLZXtYWpMv40:APA91bGXyT0xkdTuaBbn3oDJceZfSVo8fqEPBaQLu85RzpvLOHJy0hOpzRYpWuSoUVAMgly8dFSGP3lpbUG61xfETUI9iWQSOmvwb-0YorkJz_xAJMiPVE6I9EY",
    "notification":{
        "title": "Notification Title",
        "body": "Notification body",
        "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"
    },   
    "priority": "high",
    "data":{
        "content":{
            "thumbNailUrl1": "https://www.dw.com/image/49519617_303.jpg",
            "id": 100,
            "channelKey": "big_picture",
            "title": "Huston! The eagle has landed!",
            "body": "A small step for a man, but a giant leap to flutters community!",
            "notificationLayout": "BigPicture",
            "largeIcon": "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/03/19/07/34/car-7862030_960_720.jpg",
            "bigPicture" : "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/03/19/07/34/car-7862030_960_720.jpg",
            "autoDismissible": true,
            "payload":{
                "screen": "chat_screen",
                "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nasdfwyYKo"
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

This is the data in postman, for sending I got notification while app in foreground and background.

but I don't get URL and screen from payload.

```
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message) {
      // debugPrint("inside getInitial message");

      if (message.data != null) {
        print("${message.data}");

        

        // ReceivedAction receivedAction = ReceivedAction.fromJson(message.data);
     //    ReceivedAction receivedAction = ReceivedAction.fromJson(message.data);
        print("-----------------------------");
        print("data is here: ${message.data["content"]['payload']}");

 
}
```

but I can't access payload data by

```
 ${message.data["content"]['payload']}"
```

what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

it will appear `data` only accept `{String:String}` format. Try to remove `content` and make `screen` and `url` same level with other data. It is a parse error of the remote message. You can try to

```
// it will print true indicate content is String -> not in Json format
debugPrint(message.data["content"] is String ? "true" : "false")
```

My suggestion:

Try to change to this format or using `JsonFormatter` to format `data.message`

```
{
    "to":"NTQyLZXtYWpMv40:APA91bGXyT0xkdTuaBbn3oDJceZfSVo8fqEPBaQLu85RzpvLOHJy0hOpzRYpWuSoUVAMgly8dFSGP3lpbUG61xfETUI9iWQSOmvwb-0YorkJz_xAJMiPVE6I9EY",
    "notification":{
        "title": "Notification Title",
        "body": "Notification body",
        "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"
    },   
    "priority": "high",
    "data":{
        
            "thumbNailUrl1": "https://www.dw.com/image/49519617_303.jpg",
            "id": 100,
            "channelKey": "big_picture",
            "title": "Huston! The eagle has landed!",
            "body": "A small step for a man, but a giant leap to flutters community!",
            "notificationLayout": "BigPicture",
            "largeIcon": "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/03/19/07/34/car-7862030_960_720.jpg",
            "bigPicture" : "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/03/19/07/34/car-7862030_960_720.jpg",
            "autoDismissible": true,
            "screen": "chat_screen",
            "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nasdfwyYKo"
            
            
        
    }
}
```

Google Document about Data section Screenshot:

[image: Google Document about Data section]

Error while parsing Screenshot:

[image: Error while parsing]